# Disable Field via Observer

Tags: magento

So I have my Observer.php in my custom module. From there I want to set the field "is_active" to be disabled. My problem is is that is_active is a default field so its all ready be added in Main.php. I'm needing something equivalent to `$model->setData` but instead more like `$model->setAttribut('is_active', 'disabled', true)`... I've been googling and googling and searching through the code and can't seem to find a solution. So if anyone has any thoughts that would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: `is_active` for which entity? What event are you observing? Should the value for this field always be disabled? More info please.

Comment: im not sure what you mean by which entity?... I'm observing adminhtml_cms_page_edit_tab_main_prepare_form.. as far as the if it should be disabled or not doesn't matter because I can just throw the toggle in there later. Anyway I figured it out below, thank you for taking your time to help me out though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figures as soon as I break down and go to ask on here how to do something I figure it out here it is.

```
$event = $observer->getEvent();
$form = $event->getForm();    
$form->getElement('is_active')->setData('disabled', true);
```